# How to develop an Plone CMS application with an IDE?

Tags: ide, content-management-system, plone

I am looking to adopt Plone as CMS solution and want to know is there any IDE available to do all the programming for Plone CMS?

Comment: vim is your favorite IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plone is written in Python and any Python IDE is good.

I personally used Aptana Studio 3 (Eclipse + PyDev) before moving to Sublime Text 2 one year ago.

Setting up Eclipse for Plone tutorial (old):

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/developing-plone-with-eclipse

Some sample integration scripts for Eclipse for Plone (no longer work with the latest Aptana as it doesn't ship with MonkeyEclipse):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.eclipsescripts

How to tune Sublime Text 2 for Plone and Python

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/

Here are the pros and cons why I moved from Aptana to Sublime Text 2

Aptana + PyDev

- Integrated Git and SVN explorer
- You can click tracebaxk in a console window and it will take you to the line in that exception
- Autocompletion
- Linter warns on the background about bad code
- Hard to integrate with other Python tools (buildout, eggs). In fact you spend more time fighting with IDE than running the commands directly from the command line.
- In dynamic languages like Python you cannot apply most of Eclipse's powerful code analysis and refactoring features which are desgined Java in mind.

Sublime Text 2

- Faaast. In fact has 3D acceleration.
- Quick go to anywhere (CMD+T) is the best what any IDE or editor can provide. Makes your working and navigating source really efficient.
- Autocompletion (SublimeCodeIntel, works in fact better than in Eclipse)
- Linter warns on the background about bad code
- PEP-8 style guide check
- Needs some time to set-up and get confortable with
- Kind of integrated SVN and Git, but does not come even close the level of Eclipse
- Still haven't figured out how to run Plone process in a window to make tracebacks clickable

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an IDE to be a plone-developer but an good editor or a IDE might help your productivity depending on your style of coding.

Some options for good editors and IDE's are:

- [sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com) (commercial, see http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers for some tips on how to setup sublime for plone-development. If setup smartly it is a true IDE)
- [textmate](http://macromates.com/) (mac only, open source since version 2)
- vim
- emacs
- [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) (open source, a eclipse-spinnoff which includes pydev)
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (open source, you might want pydev and other addons)
- [Wing IDE](http://wingide.com) (commercial)
- [ploneide](https://github.com/collective/collective.ploneide) (a IDE running on top of Plone, still work in progress)

I now use sublime after having used Eclipse/Apatana Studio for a long time.

Comment: Well, and what about WING Ide?

Comment: True. I added Wing IDE to the list. I never used it but i know people who like it.

Answer (score 2):

The plone.ide is a recent effort by Franco Pellegrini to produce a user-friendly IDE for Plone. Give it a spin.

https://github.com/collective/collective.ploneide

Answer (score 1):

You haven't ask for a free solution.
So you must read a very good analysis at this Lennart's post and (all) comments:
[Is there a better Python IDE](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/is-there-a-better-python-ide/)

My choice is WingIDE. Is commercial, but also free depending on your project.

Keep in mind that it is written in pure python and you are going to write python code.
It has specific project settings to develop zope application and you can start to code in a couple of minutes after downloading it.

It has a debugger that binds with zope process and provide you live breakpoint capabilities. Just need to add "WingDBG" in eggs section of your buildout.

You are free to learn all other features by yourself, just google it.

Answer (score -1):

Take look at the [IDE](http://plone.org/products/zope-externaleditor-client) that you can use to consomise the CMS related stuff for PLONE.

Comment: This is not what was asked in the question